# Test Angular 2 Component with Constructor Parameter

Tags: unit-testing, angular, testing, typescript

Say I have an Angular 2 Component with two input parameters:

```
@Component{... (omitted for clarity)}
export class SomeComponent {

@Input() a: number
@Input() b: number

}
```

When I want to test this component I have something like:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        SomeComponent,
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

The `createComponent` call does not take any parameters or allow me to call the constructor. How can I instantiate/test the component for various number values?

Comment: `component.a = 1; component.b = 2;` ?

Comment: That would alter the value after instantiation. This would cause the templates of the html to use the constructor values which are (default) 0 at that time.

Comment: That's the only way to set these values. You can't change the fields of an object without first constructing the object. And you can do that before calling fixture.detectChanges().

Comment: My previous comment is not completely true: The templates do get the values set in the component in the way @JBNizet suggested. It made my tests pass. Thanks! Could you convert it in an answer so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed ou by JB Nizet, when a component has @input parameters, you need to init them in the beforeEach() :
```

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.a = 1;
    component.b = 2;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

```

Comment: const injector = Injector.create({providers: [{provide: SelfService, useClass: MockSelfService, deps: []}]});
    component.selfService = injector.get(SelfService);

If SelfService depends on http for example one can create it via injector

Comment: All these actions happen after createComponent() is called. So it will work after constuctor finishes. Therefore, you will not be able to set readonly properties.